# Java LocalDateTime vs ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, java-time

I'm creating a backend service that should do some requests to third party services and make updates based on responses. Single job is made of thousands of tiny jobs. Exact time of `begin` and `end` of main job and also `begin` and `end` of each child job should be stored in a report.
The main job would be also available to run from web user interface which means other time zone depending on user logged in.

Initial idea (and implementation) was to store `ZoneId` at the very beginning of a main job (the one from local server if job is started as a scheduled or the one from logged in user if user starts the job manually) and then use `LocalDateTime` to store `begin` and `end` of main job and child jobs. Or should I use `Instant` instead of `LocalDateTime` in that case?

```
private ZoneId zoneId;
private LocalDateTime begin;
private LocalDateTime end;
```

I'm not sure is it the right way to go with `ZoneId` or should I use `ZonedDateTime` for each `begin` and `end` and forget about stand alone `ZoneId` property.

```
private ZonedDateTime begin;
private ZonedDateTime end;
```

---

EDIT: Just to give more information for future readers:

**Case 1** will be cron job which will run once daily at some time (not so important which time, but each day the same time) and reporting will say "started job at", "finished job at".

**Case 2** will be when one clicks "run update now" and the same job will run and will generate the same report.

Comment: One issue with using LocalDateTime: it can be ambiguous. If you went with the first design, with a zone ID of "Europe/London", and begin/end values of 2023-10-29T01:15:00 and 2023-10-29T01:45:00, is that a) half an hour; b) an hour and a half; c) invalid? (It could be any of them, because 1:15am and 1:45 am each happen twice this coming Sunday in London...)

Comment: Or use Instant if the job doesn't have an *inherent* time zone and you want to be able to report it in any time zone you want. It's hard to know what to advise without more context, really.

Comment: If things are scheduled significantly in the future though, using Instant could create a problem: if the user has scheduled it to start at (say) 9am in a year's time, and the time zone rules change between now and then, if you've only recorded an instant, then you could end up starting it at 10am or 8am. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/ for more details. Life is complicated :(

Comment: `Instant.now()` is your friend here.

Answer (score 7):

`LocalDateTime` represents more or less exactly what its name is. It represents human reckoning time concepts (so, years, months, days, hours - that sort of thing. In contrast to 'millis since some epoch' which is computer reckoning time concepts).

**And no timezone at all**. Thus, given a `LocalDateTime` object, it is **not possible** to compare it to, say, an epoch-milli such as what you obtained from `System.currentTimeMillis()`, or another LDT object unless you can guarantee that it is sourced from the same timezone. Which, in your question's text, you *are not* - it depends on whether the system started the job (in which case you get the system default tz. Which can also change!), or the user started it (in which case you get their tz). Thus, given 2 LDTs in your system you can't tell which one came before or after.

You don't even need to involve multiple TZs. All we need is daylight savings.

Let's say I do something, here in Europe/Amsterdam: I start a job.

You use LDTs and dutifully log it:

```
ZoneId getUserZone() {
  return ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam");
}

ZoneId zone = getUserZone();
LocalDateTime eventStamp = LocalDateTime.now(zone);
logSystem.write(eventStamp, "User logged in");
```

Half an hour later, I log out. Same code.

A day later you check the log messages. And you witness this:

```
[2023-March-26 02:40] User logged in
[2023-March-26 02:10] User logged out
```

What the WHAT NOW?? how the heck can the logout event be in the log file with an *earlier* timestamp? For that matter, how come the log file's lexical order doesn't line up with the timestamp order? Did... did I invent a time machine?

No - daylight savings happened. The clocks were turned back an hour.

LDTs don't store any of that.

**They are therefore horrible things to use for exact time keeping**.

They represent off-the-cuff remarks such as 'I was born 14th of april 1975'. Generally you don't follow up that question with 'oh, really? Well, which timezone then?'. If I'm born in New York, 23:00 on april 14th and I move to europe, I don't then start celebrating my birthday on the 15th. Even though if we do exact timezone bookkeeping I should; New York is 6 to 7 hours 'before' europe, so when you were born, it was 05:00 in the morning on the **15th** in europe.

Be that as it may, you still don't update your birthdate. Hence, had you tracked 'born' as a ZonedDateTime and then try to calculate the difference in years between `ZonedDateTime.now("Europe/Amsterdam")` and your birth date, then on the 15th, it'd go up by one. Which would be wrong.

That's a semantic model (your birthday is stated in year, month, and date - and has no timezone component, and nobody acts like it does either) that says: Use `LocalDate` / `LDT` to represent me.

In contrast, let's say you make an appointment at a barber in Amsterdam for April 30th, 2026, 1 o'clock in the afternoon. If you store that just as LocalDateTime `2026-04-30 13:00:00`, then if you aren't in Amsterdam any alarm clock or agenda system is going to mess up when trying to tell you how many hours until your barber appointment.

If you store it as epochmillis instead, that's **also** wrong. Imagine (and this is not exotic *at all*, the EU already decided daylight saving's gotta go, there's just no timeline for it *yet*) the hammer comes down in the political chambers in NL 'starting with 2025 we shall remain on wintertime permanently'. And let's say you have a clock that is ticking down the hours and minutes until your barber's appointment.

The moment that hammer slams down, that is the moment that clock should adjust 'hours until barber appointment' down by 1 hour exactly. Because your appointment is **still** '1 o'clock in amsterdam in the afternoon on april 30th 2026'. But that's now going to be an hour earlier.

Hence, storing appointments screams: "use ZonedDateTime". Because ZDT **will** update properly (not as the hammer falls, but as the tzdata files get updated to reflect that political decision).

log events are on an exact moment in time. Therefore, the proper representation for then is **neither ZDT nor LDT**. It's `java.time.Instant`.

However, converting Instants to ZDTs and back _for events that happened in the past) is generally safe. So, if Instant isn't on the table, ZDT is wrong semantically, but won't result in errors.

Instants don't have a timezone either, but they do represent an exact moment in time. That makes them comparable (it doesn't matter that clocks move back and forth - instants don't 'do' timezones at all, and everybody's java VMs all around the planet return the same `long` value, plus minus a few due to clocks not being exactly correct, when you call `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `Instant.now()`.

When rendering log files to users, well, humans tend to be really bad at putting 'this log was written on 1698159191068. We like those years and such. But, the semantic concept you are storing **is an `Instant`**. So store that, and when rendering it to users, convert that instant to whatever is appropriate. For example, it's not crazy to turn that Instant into an LDT using the user's known timezone when showing the log to that user.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your Question mixes two very different things:

- Scheduling an appointment.
- Tracking history, the moment something happened, a **specific point on the timeline**.

If you want to schedule your task for next Monday at 3 PM:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate nextMonday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
LocalTime targetTime = LocalTime.of( 3 , 0 ) ;
```

Store those three fields (`z`, `nextMonday`, `targetTime`) if you are not yet ready to determine a moment (or, alternatively, store the date and time together as a `LocalDateTime`). Politicians frequently change the offset of the time zone(s) under their jurisdiction, and often do so with little or no forewarning. So if performing the task at 3 PM is important, defer the determination of a moment.

To determine a moment:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( nextMonday , targetTime , z ) ;
```

Adjust to UTC (an offset of zero).

```
Instant then = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Determine time to elapse:

```
Duration d = Duration.between ( Instant.now() , then ) ;
```

To record when your sub-tasks actually run, capture the current moment.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
…
Instant end = Instant.now() ;
```

When writing out text such as to a log, simply call `Instant#toString` to generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.

Use UTC (offset of zero) and `Instant` wherever you can. When wearing your “Programmer” hat, forget about your own parochial time zone. Think, log, and store in UTC. Keep a second clock in your office set to UTC. Apply time zones only (a) where required by business rules, and (b) for presentation to the user.

Comment: Thank you very much! My question is not so clear, I see now. It's not mixing two things - both are the same. 1st thing should be cron job which will run once daily at any time and reporting will say "started job at", "finished job at". 2nd thing is when one click "run update now" and the same job will run and will generate the same report. I have to sit and read everything here twice and decide for the best option.

Comment: Probably I'll calculate time spent on job and display it in reporting, but right now it's not so important.